# How to call Lua functions from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, lua, luainterface, lua.net

I use the LuaInterface library to run the lua in .net and it works fine. I could access the CLR via lua. But how to call Lua function from C#?

Comment: Maybe you have same problem as me
[same problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856826/c-external-library-lua-call-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get a reference to a `LuaFunction`, from which you can use the Call() function.

<s>Sample code can be found on [this website](http://www.youngcoders.com/net-programming/30025-luainterface-explained.html).</s>

It seems that in the last 3 years or so, LuaInterface has become a bit less popular and less supported.

In any case, [here's a newer link to a Channel 9 blog post that has some sample code](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Adding-Lua-scripting-to-your-Net-app-or-game).

Comment: Lua l = new Lua();
l.DoFile("log.lua");    
LuaFunction f = _LuaTestManager["log_info"] as LuaFunction;
if (f != null)
   f.Call("My log message");

Made it. Thanks

Comment: @SteveFolly I've edited my comment. It's been a long while since I've worked with Lua in C# and as I state in my comment, it seems to have become a bit less popular. The LuaInterface seems to not be too active.

Comment: 2nd link is broken too. Some of the pictures are missing.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the pictures are broken in accepted answer, so I decided to add new answer.

This solution requires you to install NLua NuGet to your project first.
Let's say, that we need to get some table, or just sum up two variables.
Your Test.lua file will contain:

```
-- Function sums up two variables
function SumUp(a, b)
    return a + b;
end

function GetTable()
    local table =
    {
        FirstName = "Howard",
        LastName = "Wolowitz",
        Degree = "just an Engineer :)",
        Age = 28
    };

    return table;
end;
```

Your C# code will look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Lua lua = new Lua();
            lua.DoFile(@"D:\Samples\Test.lua");

            // SumUp(a, b)
            var result = lua.DoString("return SumUp(1, 2)");
            Console.WriteLine("1 + 2 = " + result.First().ToString());

            // GetTable()           
            var objects = lua.DoString("return GetTable()"); // Array of objects
            foreach (LuaTable table in objects)
                foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> i in table)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i.Key.ToString()}: {i.Value.ToString()}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```